# Mostrar datos de una columna de DataGridView en float

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Windows C# el cual toma la orden dentro de un datagridview y al presionar el botón "calcular total" tiene que sumar la columna de "Costo". El problema es que no me respeta los decimales ya que en muestra todo el numero como entero como la siguiente imagen lo muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En vez de mostrarme 65.5 me muestra 655.

Este es el código que uso al presionar el botón:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; numColumna++)
            {
                float sumTotal =0F;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                { 
                    sumTotal += Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells[1].Value);  
                }
                textBox1.Text = sumTotal.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Intente meterlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; numColumna++)
            {
               var sumTotal ="";

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {

                    sumTotal +=Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
                    Convert.ToSingle(sumTotal);
                    MessageBox.Show(sumTotal);
                    }
                MessageBox.Show(sumTotal);
                textBox1.Text = sumTotal.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Y lo que pasa es que al momento de hacer la suma ahora me aparece de la siguiente forma:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nada más dale formato al pasarlo a texto, por ejemplo sumTotal.ToString("#,0.00");

Comment: Buena tarde  @shop350 me sigue dando el mismo problema pero ahora me muestra  655,00 en vez de 65.5

Comment: Intenta forzando la cultura sumTotal.ToString("#,0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX"));

Comment: ya te fijaste si no hay alguna especie de validación en algún evento del textbox que haga que se elimine el punto?

Comment: Tenia el siguiente error en la consulta, no sabia que la funcion RTRIM y LTRIM quitaban las "," y ".": SqlDataAdapter agregar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select  (RTRIM(LTRIM(Nombre))) as Nombre,(RTRIM(LTRIM(Costo))) as Costo from entradas where Nombre = 'Dedos de queso' and costo= '79.50'", cadena);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigos, gracias por la ayuda, el error se encontraba en la consulta, no sabia que la funcion RTRIM y LTRIM quitaban las "," y ".":

```
SqlDataAdapter agregar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select  (RTRIM(LTRIM(Nombre))) as Nombre,(RTRIM(LTRIM(Costo))) as Costo from entradas where Nombre = 'Dedos de queso' and costo= '79.50'", cadena);
```

Modificada:

```
 SqlDataAdapter agregar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select  (RTRIM(LTRIM(Nombre))) as Nombre,Costo from entradas where Nombre = 'Dedos de queso' and costo= '79.50'", cadena);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar los especificadores de formato numérico estándar en el método `ToString()`. Puedes revisarlos en este [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

En tu caso en particular, para obtener en `string` el número exacto puedes usar el especificador "R", por ejemplo:

```
float sumTotal = 65.5f;
string numberString = sumTotal.ToString("R");
```

Comment: Buena tarde Mario, me sigue mostrando el mismo valor, lo que pasa es que el valor del float sumTotal  no es fijo va cambiando.